# Global Site Tag (gtag) doesn't send anything

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

I've set up a new Analystics account, and copied over the tracking code. It's of the kind

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXX-X"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X');
</script>
```

I then track an event using

```
gtag('event', 'click', {
  event_category: 'acquisition',
  event_action: 'click',
  event_label: 'download',
  event_value: 1
});
```

I've tried all kinds of gtag() syntax, however nothing ever gets sent to Analytics. When checking the Network tab in Chrome debug tools, there is no communication with Google at all. (the dataLayer array is properly populated)

I don't want to use Google Tag Manager, just looking for a simple "track event via Javascript".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is working, might be a local computer/browser addon that's blocking the call to GA[image]

Comment: I'm afraid {foobar: 3} and {'foobar': 3} yield the exact same object in Javascript, so the quotes cannot be the issue. Removing the event_action property has no effect, still nothing recorded.

Comment: Can you share the code that shows how you’ve implemented gtag and where you sent the event?

Comment: I've edited the question to include the full setup (it's a standard copy/paste from the code Google provides). Debugging shows the gtag call is made, and completes without any exception. Only, nothing ever gets sent to analytics.

Comment: Can you include the full page you're having issues with? Remove the UA? You're saying everything is standard, but nothing is getting sent. Leads me to think something on the page is affecting the tracking OR it is local to you. Are you at least getting the pageview hit?

Comment: The page is publicly available at https://isthmus.want.ch. Clicking the download at the very bottom of the page should register an event.

Comment: I just had a look and everything is working fine. https://imgur.com/a/IyeLObr how are you verifying if the tag works or not?

Comment: thank you so much for your help! I'm checking my Chrome debugger network tab, and looking at Behavior -> Events -> Overview in Analystics. The latter shows your 2 clicks, so now I know it's working I can start figuring out if I have an adblocker/malware scanner/disconnect something installed on my computer. If you post a solution along the lines of local browser add-on blocking the 'collect' call, I'll mark it as answer.

Comment: Oh my, it's late and I think I edited the wrong thing, haha...but glad I could help!